# How to bypass NTFS file permissions?

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs

Recently I had permissions problems with Windows Search, then I run Permissions Time Machine to restore the permissions to default (according [this topic](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/36379-windows-search-indexing-broken-post528068.html))

After this, I receive a blue screen on startup, with the 0xC000021A code.

In Advanced Startup Options, I receive an "access denied" for all files that I try access in command prompt!

However, I can access all these files by Ubuntu Live CD. There are a way to recover the permissions without reinstall Windows?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with **enough detail to identify an adequate answer**.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
 sudo chmod -R -f 777 (your hard disk path)
```

on the Ubuntu Live CD (after mounting your hard disk)

(your hard disk path) would be, for example, `/media/live/disk/*` rather then `C:\` or `/dev/sdb2`.

But BE WARNED: 777 applies read, write, and execute to the files. Some Windows files are not supposed to have these permissions (in Linux permission style, they would be closer to`-rwxr-----` then `-rwxrwxrwx`).

I have not tested this command but your system should boot afterwards.

Comment: Does CHMOD know how to rewrite NTFS ACLs/security descriptors?

Comment: @DawnBenton It should. If not, refer to the 7th answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition).

Comment: I created a test file in other partition and removed my own permission. Then, I tested this command on the Ubuntu with this file, logged on Windows and does not work.